# Referencing non-static fields from static functions and vice versa impossible?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, static

I want to programmatically determine the space I've got for some controls I want to create dynamically. So, I want to get the container's height and divide it by the number of rows (a constant).

I've got this function (this code is part of the form on which the panel named dynamicPanel lives):

```
private static int getControlHeightToUse() {
  return (dynamicPanel.Height / NUMBER_OF_ROWS);
}
```

...which gives me the compile-time error, "*An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property RememberNextGen_CRLogins.CRLoginsMainForm.dynamicPanel'*"

I don't understand what it's trying to tell me/what it wants.

If I remove the "static":

```
private int getControlHeightToUse() {
  return (dynamicPanel.Height / NUMBER_OF_ROWS);
}
```

...I then get the compile-time error, "*A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'TitanNextGen_CRLogins.CRLoginsMainForm.getControlHeightToUse()'*"

...on the indicated line below:

```
public partial class CRLoginsMainForm : Form {

  int controlHeight = getControlHeightToUse(); // <-- err
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `static` method has only direct access to `static` memebers of the class, if you want to use instance members of the class, you must pass in an instance of the class to the method (or have one available as a `static` as in the case of a singleton).

Thus, you can modify your method to take in the instance member that is preventing it from being able to be static:

```
private static int getControlHeightToUse(Panel thePanel) 
{
  return (thePanel.Height / NUMBER_OF_ROWS);
}
```

Then just pass in `dynamicPanel` on the call...

Instance methods, however, can access `static` members.  Remember that `static` members are shared among all instances and exist even if no instance of the class exist.  Thus they can't call instance members since they don't know which instance you are talking about.

Comment: If a class that inherited the `Panel` class was passed to getControlHeightToUse, would this code still work?

Answer (score 2):

pass dynamicPanel as parameter to static method

```
public partial class CRLoginsMainForm : Form {

  int controlHeight = getControlHeightToUse(dynamicPanel);
```

change getControlHeightToUse as below

```
private static int getControlHeightToUse(Panel panel) {
  return (panel.Height / NUMBER_OF_ROWS);
}
```

if you want to call non static method from static method you can do as below

```
public class Foo
{
    // public method 
    public void Method1()
    {
    }

    public static void Data2()
    {
        // call public method from static method
        new Foo().Method1();

    }
}
```