# c# call windows form from static function

Tags: c#, forms, static

I have to add a item in the listBox1 from a static function, but it doens't work because of the static^^; is it possible to call windows forms (like the listBox1) from a static function in c#?

what i want to do:

```
public static void ListBoxTest() 
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("something");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Referencing non-static fields from static functions and vice versa impossible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251599/referencing-non-static-fields-from-static-functions-and-vice-versa-impossible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access non-static methods inside the static method without creating an instance, else you can use something like the following, by Changing the function signature :

```
public static void ListBoxTest(ListBox listBox1) 
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("something");
}
```

and call the function as:

```
ListBoxTest(listBox1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this;

```
private static Form1 _instance;

public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   _instance = this;
}

public static void ListBoxTest() 
{
    _instance.listBox1.Items.Add("something");
}
```